# Turn off (asus) touchpad PalmCheck/SmartSense without Synaptics control panel

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, touchpad, asus

Please help.

I've been struggling with this for ever, and I just don't understand why Microsoft and Synaptics would take the horrible idea of setting this feature as the default.

So, SmartSense / PalmCheck freezes your mouse for a few seconds any time you press a key. For gaming this is a disaster, try moving with WASD and you can not longer point/aim.

However, I don't have a HKLM/Software/Synaptics/SynTP or Defaults key in my registry, only SynTPEnh.

**There is no option to turn off PalmCheck / SmartSense / anything of the sort in Windows 10's "Touchpad Settings"**

For touchpads with a Synaptics control panel, this is very simple. You go to the settings and turn PalmCheck off, or change some settings in the registry. I don't have a Synaptics control panel, and I don't have the keys I've found online in my registry.

I remember fixing this issue myself before I had refreshed my laptop, but it involved a lot of shady business with drivers and I didn't really know what I was doing, but I got rid of it - so it's definitely possible.

please

send help

I have an **Asus ROG Strix GL503VD**

Answer (score 2):

Setting "Touchpad sensitivity" under "Taps" to "Most sensitive" in the touchpad settings gets rid of this problem.